# Convert a string value into PlaceHolder id

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-placeholder

As a newbie I have tried several Google searches and have found a few confusing answers.  What I am trying to achieve is:

1. click on a button (one of many),
2. extract that button's text value, then
3. use that value to make the relevant placeholder visible.

So far I have done the first 2 steps but how do I accomplish step 3?  My code so far, which works if I click on the `Asia` button, is:

```
protected void btnArea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ar = (sender as Button).Text;
    //ar = "Asia";
    phdasia.Visible = true;
}
```

In simple, newbie friendly terms, what do I have to insert in place of `phdasia`?

Answer (score 1):

If your placeholder controls share the same name format you may be able to reach them by name:

```
protected void btnArea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ar = (sender as Button).Text;
    //ar = "Asia";
    string name = "phd" + ar.ToLower(); // The naming format comes here
    Control[] controls = this.Controls.Find(name, true); //find the control(s) by name

    foreach(Control control in controls) // mow loop and make them visible
        control.Visible = true;
    //phdasia.Visible = true;
}
```

**Edit**: alternatively you can use `FindControl` method to locate a control with an ID property of `"phdasia"` on the containing page:

```
Control control = FindControl(name);
if(control!=null)
    control.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Not only does it work but I understand it!